# MOSS 2007 upgrade to SP2 failed with "...SPFarm.Local indicates that this machine is not joined."

Tags: 2007, upgrade, service-pack

I went throught the following procedure to upgrade MOSS 2007 to SP2, and managed to break the my dev environment. Despite the error message mentioned above, my installation is the trivial case of one FE server. The content databases are on a separate cluster however.

- Ran officeserver2007sp2-kb953334-x86-fullfile-en-us.exe to upgrade MOSS 2007 SP1 to SP2, which failed and told me to proceed to install WSS 3.0, SP2 first.
- Ran wssv3sp2-kb953338-x86-fullfile-en-us.exe to install WSS 3.0, SP2, which failed and left the following error messsages in the logs.

> 03/06/2012 10:02:07  1  ERR          Discovered a v3 connection
>   string and SPFarm.Local indicates that this machine   is not joined. 
>   Therefore we failed to determine if we were joined to a server farm.
>   ... 03/06/2012 10:02:07  1  ERR        Failed to successfully try to
>   see if this server is joined to the server farm.    The operation will
>   continue so that you can force a disconnect from a server farm that
>   cannot be contacted ...

- I opened Central Admin, but SharePoint Central Admin fails with the following text in the browser: Server error: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=96177
- Restarted the server and reran the upgrade.
  'Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 Service Pack 2 (SP2)
  The update is already installed on this system.`
- Installed and ran the Windows Service Monitor from Codeplex. All services appear to be running.

Now I cannot access the central administration or the front end. Can anyone tell me how to roll-back my disaster, and hopefully what I did wrong?

**EDIT**
I should add the following stack trace from the front-end:

> Stack Trace:  [SPUpgradeException: An error has occurred on the
>   server.http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=96177]
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPContentDatabase.ValidateDatabaseSchemaCompatibility()
>   +1803    Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.PreinitializeServer(SPRequest request) +59    Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.InitializeSPRequest() +290 
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.EnsureSPRequest() +58
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.get_Request() +54
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControl.SPWebEnsureSPControl(HttpContext
>   context) +400
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControl.GetContextWeb(HttpContext
>   context) +31
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.PostResolveRequestCacheHandler(Object
>   oSender, EventArgs ea) +385
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +68    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try rerunning your *SharePoint Products and Technologies Configuration Wizard* as that will sometimes repair situations like this.

Comment: It's a bit late but I found the technet article, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263467(v=office.12).aspx#section2. I'm running the MOSS SP2 with the Central Admin user (step 3 in the article). The configuration wizard should launch afterwards. I'll let you know how it went.